# How to account for shipping cost on free shipping items?

Tags: magento2, magento-1, price, free-shipping

We have some items that are free shipping. Obviously, there is a shipping cost. How do we account for this in Magento or some other solution so that we can keep track of profit/loss per order?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot from within Magento, you can set cost for a product but not the cost for shipping.

A work around would be to add the rule to the product and leave the shipping amount intact. This way you can see cost vs price.

Comment: can you help with the question - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/361248/magento-2-shipping-carrier-shipping-cost-vs-shipping-price